# How to set the date format in MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to set date in this format MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm, I hede done code for this but there is some thing wrong which I don't know.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"My date with out format = %@",date);
date = [format dateFromString:[format stringFromDate:date]];
NSLog(@"My date is = %@",date);
```

**OUTPUT**

My date with out format = 2012-06-22 09:53:46 +0000
 My date is = 2012-06-22 09:53:00 +0000

Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstoff, `NSDate` does not know any thing about the formatting of the date. Thats where `NSDateFormatter` comes in.

```
date = [format dateFromString:[format stringFromDate:date]];
```

What you are doing here is create a string for the given format, which will also result in removing the timezone. and than create a new date from that string. Since it no longer has the timezone it will result in a date with `GMT` as time zone.

But this will still result in a `NSDate` which holds, seconds and has a default time zone set to `GMT`.

There is no need to make a new date object, if you want to display a date just take the string which the `stringFromDate:` method returns. If you do it like this it will work:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"My date with out format = %@",date);
NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"My date is = %@",dateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not told the formatter to show the seconds, to do this add "HH:mm:**ss**"

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"My date with out format = %@",date);
date = [format dateFromString:[format stringFromDate:date]];
NSLog(@"My date is = %@",date);
```

Comment: Omer i dont need seconds i  need just MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm

Comment: @FaheemRajput - please edit the question to show what you want as this answer makes your format do the same as without format

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"My date with out format = %@",date);
    NSString *dateStr = [format stringFromDate:date];

    //date = [format dateFromString:[format stringFromDate:date]];
    NSLog(@"My date is = %@",dateStr);
```

Comment: You forgot to set the locale to en_US_POSIX.  You should ALWAYS do that when dealing with a defined date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [format setDateFormat:@"YYYY-dd-MM HH:mm:ss z"];
```